# ¿Cómo puedo gestionar el estado de 4 Checkbox con un componente funcional en ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

¿Qué me recomiendan para hacer un componente funcional con exactamente 4 Checkbox? Los he creado dinámicamente mapeando un Array y les coloco su valor checked de un:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([false, false, false, false])
```

y luego con una función les cambio el estado, algo tipo:

```
const checkboxes = array.map( (el, index) => {

return <Checkbox

checked={checked[index]}

onChange={checkedHandler}/>

}
```

Con un handler:

```
const checkedHandler = (event, index) => {

setChecked(...)

//Bueno, aquí me quedé corto porque no sé como cambiar el valor de un índice en concreto con ese setChecked.

}
```

¿O me veré obligado a crear un useState para cada Checkbox?

Mi problema es que no puedo manejar bien su estado `checked` con lo que pienso...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo haría un componente `Checkbox` con su estado propio. Piensa que tu solución no es fácilmente escalable ni reutilizable. ¿Qué pasaría si en vez de 4 `Checkbox` tienes 20? Tendrías que manejar un `array` como estado para todos los `Checkbox`. De la otra forma cada uno tiene su estado propio.

Mira este pequeño ejemplo. Como ves, cada componente `Checkbox` tiene su estado independiente

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Checkbox = ({ initialState, id, onChange }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(initialState);
  
  const onClick=(checked)=>{
   setChecked(checked);
   onChange(id, checked);
  }
  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onClick={e => onClick(e.target.checked)}
      checked={checked}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {

  const onCheckboxClicked=(idx, isChecked)=>{
    console.log(`I'm checkbox number ${idx} and i'm checked? --> ${isChecked}`);
    //Aquí puedes guardar estados si es necesario
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((checkbox,i) => (
        <Checkbox initialState={true} id={i+1} onChange={onCheckboxClicked} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! Entiendo la idea, gracias. No he practicado mucho con React y me tocó colaborar en el desarrollo de una página. Gracias.

Comment: Piensa además que tu componente checkbox puede crecer y tener nuevas funcionalidades con lo cual debes desacoplarlo al máximo del resto de tu código.

Comment: Aprovecho la "conversación"... y para obtener el resultado de ese Checkbox como hago? Es decir, pasarlo a su padre? Uso un Context o qué me recomiendas? No sé usar Redux.

Comment: He actualizado el ejemplo. Si quieres acceder al estado del hijo desde el padre lo mejor es que le pases una función a la que invocar desde dicho hijo con los parámetros que quieres obtener. En el ejemplo le pasamos una propiedad `onChange` que es una referencia a la función `onCheckboxClicked`. Dicha función se ejecuta en el hijo y así el padre tiene accesible el valor del estado del hijo.

Para un sólo nivel no es necesario usar el contexto (por cierto, con el `hook useContext` ya no es necesario aprender `Redux`).

Comment: Otra opción que tienes es usar el `hook useRef` que crea una referencia al elemento del DOM para poder modificar y obtener sus valores pero esto no rompe la regla de la programación declarativa y no es recomendable salvo en contadas excepciones (https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: Gracias por toda la información, intentaré aprovecharla.